# Adapter to handle requests for APIs that exists on another server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

So this is the scenario:

1. I have a server(say **SERVER A**), that has the following rest APIs

- /questionnaire/{questionnaire_id}
- /questionnaire/
- /questionnaire/question/{question_id}
- questionnaire/question/

2. Now I have a second server(say **SERVER B**), that has some other APIs.
3. Now SERVER B has a frontend(say **FRONTEND B**), that access both backend SERVER A and SERVER B

Requirements:

1. I do not want to directly access SERVER A from FRONTEND B, instead,
   I want to access backend SERVER B that will authenticate the request
   coming from FRONTEND B and in turn, hit backend SERVER A to get the
   response.
2. Now I do not want to write a duplicate APIs on SERVER B to hit the
   the corresponding APIs on SERVER A. What I want is an adapter that
   handles all API request whose URL starts with "/questionnaire/" and
   authenticate the user or request and then hit the SERVER A, receive the data
   and return it to FRONTEND B.

So is there any tool inbuilt in Django for this or if there is any workaround to make it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can "curl" your way around it. You will have to add a handler for the api on serverB, otherwise the requests can not be received. Once you get the request from your frontent you can use the python shell to call curl with the relevant parameters effectively forwarding the request to server A. The latter is not an ideal design though, You approach B as gateway while you want it to act as a router. If you want authentication allow B to issue a session token that is then passed along with each call to the A.
Here is some code to give you context

```
import os
import subprocess    
....
        
        l_strDomain = get_domain_name()
        
        
        l_cmd = 'curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"'+\
                    ' --request POST'+\
                    ' --data \'json data here if needed'+\
                    ' http://ServerA/Api/'
        
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(l_cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,encoding='utf-8').stdout
        output = p1.read()
        p1.close();
        
        try:
            l_data = simplejson.loads(output)
        except Exception as e:
            ..do errro handling
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using Api key authentication between server A and server B.

So when you get request from the user (from frontend B) to the server B.
After server B authenticate the user, you can have an middle ware which sends request to server A, using the requests module of python.

This request which is sent from server B to server B will be having API key authentication.

After you get the response from the server A you can return it to frontend.

1. [Django Rest framework Api key package](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/)

Hope this will help in solving this challenge.